# Setting up Serial USB communication between STM32 and PC with Mbed library

Tags: c++, serial-port, stm32, mbed, nucleo

I hava an [STM32 f401RE](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f401re.html). I am using [Mbed library](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.14/apis/index.html) for setting up a conexion from STM32 to PC. I want to send via serial a char sequence to the board. As an answer i expect a blinking LED. E.g: `led1` results in `LED ON`, `led2` results in `LED OFF`.

The problem is that i don't know how to set the port for the connection.

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "USBSerial.h"

//Virtual serial port over USB
USBSerial serial;

int main(void) {

    while(1)
    {
        serial.printf("I am a virtual serial port\r\n");
        wait(1.0);
    }
}
```

> You can use the USBSerial interface to emulate a serial port over USB. You can use this serial port as an extra serial port or as a debug solution. It also communicates between Mbed and a computer.

I would like to do all the above(even thogh i don't know what does *emulate a serial port over USB*. What is that Virtual USB?).

I see that `USBSerial` constructor takes 
`USBSerial (bool connect_blocking=true, uint16_t vendor_id=0x1f00, uint16_t product_id=0x2012, uint16_t product_release=0x0001)`. And i think i need to modify some of this adresses. The problem is that on `Windows` the ports are represented in Device Manager with `COMxx` and on `Linux` like `ttyACMxx`. How would i transform this in hexa adresses - is this what i have to do?

Comment: for these boards, I prefer using Arduino since serial-debugging is already implemented. See this link on how to configure the Arduino IDE: http://www.emcu.eu/2017/03/13/how-to-use-stm32-and-arduino-ide/

Comment: Sorry for my question but using arduino on this boards does it affects the performance of stm32? Does it works fully? What is the difference of using stm32 with arduino vs using stm32 using HALL vs using stm32 using Mbed?

Comment: The stm32 implementation on arduino is fine and won't slow down your performance that much.
It's a great starting point for fast prototyping.
You can also take a look at "Atollic TrueSTUDIO", it takes a bit more time to set up but "line-by-line"-debugging is a big plus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this approach and it is working. The thing that i don't understand is why on my pc i get this message: `b'Hello World!\n'`

```
#include "mbed.h"

Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX); // tx, rx

int main() {
    pc.baud(9600);

    while(1)
    {
        pc.printf("Hello World!\n");
        wait(0.1);
    }
}
```

Comment: well, that's what your code is supposed to be doing: writing the message *Hello World* in a loop to its serial port. On your computer, you are only reading what you get on the port. If you want to blink an LED when you input a key on your computer you'll have to change your code to read from the port and instruct the board to blink the LED, look at the link I posted on my comment above.

Comment: How can i get rit of the b in front of my message?

Comment: That `b` is coming from the visualization on your terminal utility, you should be able to get rid of it manipulating its settings

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to transform anything or mess with the USB `product_id` or `vendor_id`, an mbed serial port should show as any other serial port so if it doesn't for you it means you are having driver issues.

On most recent Linux distros the device should show something similar to the following kernel messages:

```
 cdc_acm 5-2:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
 usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
 cdc_acm: v0.26:USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

On Windows, you will probably need to install drivers. After you do that, the serial port should show as `mbed Serial Port (COMx)` on your Device Manager. There are many places you can get troubleshooting help, see [here](https://os.mbed.com/forum/bugs-suggestions/topic/1186/?page=1#comment-16745), for instance.

The fact that you are getting nothing on both Windows and Linux makes one wonder if you are using the right cable (some USB cables work only for charging and are no good for your purposes, and some others simply fail after a while). I would first make sure your cable works with other devices (obviously not for charging only). There is also the possibility your board went (or came from the factory) bad, but that's quite unlikely.

Comment: I made a confusion. I thought i need to setup something on PC, then something on board in order to get it functional. I can see my board as COM3 on windows. I just don't know how to setup a serial communication to my board...

Comment: I see what you mean. Then you should already have a fully functional setup. Just install any terminal utility you like (TeraTerm, RealTerm, puTTY,...), point it to COM3, boot your board and you should get *"I am a virtual serial port* on the terminal. Then you'll have to build it up from there, if you want to blink an LED you'd better take a look [here](https://os.mbed.com/handbook/SerialPC)

Answer (score 0):

Ignore that 'b'. Your device is not seeing that 'b'. It is just being printed by serial terminal utility. Also I would like to mention what I got from your question is, you want to send some data from PC to board over Serial and if device receives that data, it should start blinking the LED. If that is correct, use the code below:

```
#include "mbed.h"

Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX); // tx, rx
DigitalOut led(LED1);    // If blinking doesn't work with LED1, Check the pin map for your board and pass the LED pin instead of LED1

char token = 'a';        // This is the character that you should send to trigger blinking
bool startBlinking = false;

int main() {
    pc.baud(9600);

    while(1)
    {
        if (pc.getc() == token) {
            startBlinking = true;
        }
        if (startBlinking) {
            led = 1;
            wait(0.2);
            led = 0;
            wait(0.8);
        }
    }
}
```